# Xubuntu: Regular Freeze, can be recovered by changing to TTY

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, mouse, freeze, tty

With my Lenovo Flex 2-14 laptop (Xubuntu 14.04 installed), I'm experiencing regular complete freezes of the system (mouse and most keyboard interaction impossible, mouse pointer doesn't move anymore).

However, I found that the freeze can be resolved by just changing to any TTY and back (without doing anything else, not even logging in on the TTY). After that, I can go on working without any apparent loss of data or crashed applications.

I'm suspecting that there might be an issue related to the X server or window manager, but wasn't able to find any useful information on that so far.

So the question is: Is anybody able to deduce information related to the cause of the freezes (that occur frequently enough to be quite annoying, even though the "solution" seems to be very reliable) from my description of the "magic" remedey? - just change to one of the TTYs and back.

Thanks for any hints!